# Multiple Listboxes showing ranges from active sheets - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This is my First Ever Post:

I am creating a user form that will function similarly to a school management system.

One of the elements that are part of it is a Pupil Profile, which shows all information relating to the specific child.

Currently, each pupil has its own sheet. When searching for the child, the sheet matching the name of the child will be set as the active sheet.

This sheet contains sets of columns that store data about Parents meetings, rewards and sanctions, concerns and meetings with key staff members.

[Example Pupil Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXnoq.png)

I have a multipage setup with 4 tabs, each tab has a list box that I want to show the data from the set of columns on the active sheet.

I don't know a great deal about VBA, so I followed some tutorials and managed to make one of the sets of columns work perfectly. But to be honest, I don't understand how the code works, and I can't make it work for the other rows:

---

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long
Dim i As Long, G As Integer
Dim C As Integer, M As Integer

For G = 2 To Sheets.Count
If Sheets(G).Name = txtSearch Then
For i = 2 To Sheets(G).Range("A2000").End(xlUp).Row


Me.ListBox1.AddItem
For C = 0 To 6
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, C) = Sheets(G).Cells(i, C + 1)
Next C
Next i
End If
Next G

Private Sub AddParentMeeting_Click()
TgtSheet = txtSearch.Value
If TgtSheet = "" Then
Exit Sub
End If
Worksheets(TgtSheet).Activate
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = PM1.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = PM2.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).Value = PM3.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, 4).Value = PM4.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, 5).Value = PM5.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).Value = PM6.Value
End Sub
```

---

Basically, my two key issues are:

1. How do I populate list boxes from a range of data on the active sheet so that it changes with each new profile search? E.g

ListBox1 shows A2:F2000 on active sheet

ListBox2 shows H2:K2000 on active sheet

ListBox3 shows M2:Q2000 on active sheet

ListBox4 shows S2:X2000 on active sheet

2. How do I add information to just those columns without it adding the information to the next fully clear row? e.g)

I don't want this to happen:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75ynM.png)

I want it to look like this:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvC4Y.png)

Sorry for the lengthy post, and any questions or help in the right direction would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You may not like this reply and for that I apologize but your approach ignores all database basics. It will give you more work than need be and fail before the project is finished. The first mistake is to have a separate sheet for each pupil.

You need one sheet with a row for each pupil, columns like name, first name, middle name, birthday (not age because you can calculate the age from the birthday any time you need it), address, parent's phone etc. The first column is the most important. In db parlance it's call the "Key". It contains a unique identifier for everything in the row, a pupil number, if you like or an ID code. The point of the "key" is to be unique. By this ID you can retrieve the entire row and all information in it.

Then you need 4 more similar data bases: Parent Meetings, Staff Meetings, Concerns, Rewards/Consequences. Each of these has the columns you already designed plus one more which is called the "Foreign Key". In each row of these tables you enter the "Key" from the Pupils sheet, linking each entry - Meeting, Concern or Reward - to one particular pupil. Perhaps you have a validation drop-down with the pupils' names to avoid typos in the Keys. But that is already step 2.

You would be able to work with this setup immediately. Simply filter any of the lists on a pupil's ID to get a list of all meetings, concerns or rewards for any one pupil. With the help of the "Key" you would be able to easily and quickly create a sheet with the pupil's details at the top, meetings, concerns, rewards listed - much like your existing pupil sheets but with changing data as you select a pupil from a validation drop-down. All done with VLOOKUP and worksheet functions. No user form yet. That would be the de-luxe version but you would have 80% of the functionality while you work on it.

Comment: I really appreciate that answer! Has given me a lot to work on. How would I make the listbox only show the information for one ID code? for example when I search the profile, show only the Parent Meetings for that Child/ID Code

Comment: Say, I wanted all parent meetings of one child, I would loop through all the meetings and add those where the ID = Key to the list box. If the number of meetings in the db is very large I might use `Find` and `FindNext` to pick out rows with the matching Key or use VBA to apply a filter.